# Problem with Office Web Apps

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps

Office Web App Server will not work correctly with my Sharepoint Server  (2013).

When ever I try to open or edit a document via web app it keeps giving me the

> Sorry there was a problem and we can't open this document.

I know the Office Web App Server was set up correctly, gave me the xml file and plus I tried it into Exchange and it works just dandy with it.

- I have unbound the server four times and re bound it and made sure that I ran `Set-SPWOPIZone` command for external and https.
- I have added the domain to the Trusted list on the Wac Server.
- I have also made sure that the AllowOAuthOverHttp was false.

I have no clue what to do any more it works with Lync and Exchange. [image]

Comment: Could you provide some more information on your configuration? Please run a "Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm" on your OWA-Server and a "Get-SPWopiZone" and a "Get-SPWOPIBinding" (1 result is enough). It is also important to know if your SharePoint WebApplications are accessed through SSL.

Comment: Can you check the certificate name if correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your OWA server can resolve the ip address of the site-collection that hosts your document